# Independence and the Borel-Cantelli lemma

Tags: probability-theory

The second Borel-Cantelli lemma says that if $A_n$ are independent and $\sum_{n}^{} P(A_n) = \infty$, then $P(A_n \ \text{i.o.}) = 1.$ Let's take away the assumption of independence for a second. Consider $\sum_{n}^{} 1_{A_n}$. Then,

$$\mathbb{E}\left [ \sum_{n}^{}1_{A_n} \right ] = \sum_{n}^{} \mathbb{E}[1_{A_n}] = \sum_{n}^{}P(A_n) = \infty.$$

So, if the expected value of the sum of the indicator functions goes to infinity, why doesn't that mean that $P(A_n \ \text{i.o.}) = 1$?

Comment: $A_n$ independent with $\sum P(A_n)=\infty$ implies $P(A_n\text{ i.o.})=1$ yes? That is the 2nd Borel-Cantelli I am familiar with. Your first sentence is contrary to that.

Comment: @jdods OP said 'take away independence for  a second'.

Comment: @geetha290krm What am I missing about the first sentence in the post?

Comment: @jdods Nothing. I just defined what the Borel-Cantelli Lemma is.

Comment: So is it really true that $A_n$ independent, $\sum P(A_n)=\infty$ implies $P(A_n\text{ i.o.})=0$? I am claiming your first sentence is wrong.

Comment: @jdods It was a typo sorry.

Answer (score 0):

$X$ non-negative and $EX=\infty$ does not tell you that $P(X=\infty)=1$. There are easy counter-examples: If $X$ takes the values $1,2,3,\cdots$ with $P(X=n)=\frac  c {n^{2}}$ wher $c=\frac 6 {\pi^{2}}$ then $P(X=\infty)=0$ even though $EX=\sum \frac  c n=\infty$.

What is true is that $X \geq 0, EX <\infty$ implies $P(X<\infty)=1$ but  this does not help.

Comment: That makes sense. What if instead of independence, we have $P(A_m \cap A_n) \leq P(A_m) P(A_n)$? I feel like indicator functions could help here.

Comment: @MathIsLife12 You can have complicated dependence which means the probability infinitely many of the events occur is something other than zero or one as well. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088046/what-do-these-alternative-formulations-of-the-second-borel-cantelli-lemma-durre although that doesn't exactly tell you explicitly what I am saying here.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide a somewhat complicated example but attempt to do so in intuitive terms. This is less of an answer as that has already been given: that infinite expected value can still have probability of being infinite not equaling one, e.g. equal to zero. I am just providing an example where the probability of something infinitely often is positive but not one.

Consider the contact process which is an interacting particle system which models the spatial spread of an infection. I won't give any details here though. Bascially, the infection lives on an integer lattice. Each point on the lattice can be infected or healthy. Infected sites recover and become healthy according to an exponential random wait with mean one. Infected sites also try to infect nearby sites according to exponential waits. As long as the infection spreading exponential clock ticks sufficiently fast, then the infection has a chance at spreading forever.

Consider the scenario where the origin is the only infected site. Define the events $A_n$ to be the origin has recovered and be infected for the $n^{th}$ time. Let $\tau_n$ be the time that the origin becomes infected for the $n^{th}$ time (after being infected exactly $n-1$ distinct times before and having recovered from each), so $A_n=\{\tau_n<\infty\}$. If the origin recovers and never becomes infected again, then we set $\tau_n=\infty$ for all later $n$. The events $A_n$ are not independent, although I don't provide any details. It is a standard result in contact process theory that $P(A_n\text{ i/o.})>0$ for suitable model parameters, though we definitely have that $P(A_n\text{ i.o.})<1$ as there is clearly a positive probability that the origin dies, say within the first unit of time, before spreading any infection whatsoever.

Though every time the origin is newly reinfected we have $P(B_n)>\epsilon>0$ for some lower bound $\epsilon>0$, hence $\sum P(B_n)=\infty$.

I am not really able to provide any details, but two references are Liggett's two books *Interacting Particle Systems* and *Stochastic Interacting Systems*.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial counterexample, on the probability space consisting of $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure: $$A_n=\chi_{[0,1/n]}.$$